# Toggle UIBarButtonItem on UIToolbar

Tags: swift, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

I want to add a play/pause type button to a `UIToolbar` but I'm unsure how to access the button in code. I've tried to add an outlet for the button and change it that way but it doesn't change this way so I'm obviously not doing it correctly.

```
@IBOutlet weak var playPauseButton: UIBarButtonItem!

func toggleButton() {

    playPauseButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Stop, target: self, action: "stop:")

}
```

**Edit: The solution I came up with was the following:**

(Thanks wltrup for pointing me in the right direction!)

```
var isActive = false
@IBOutlet weak var toolbar: UIToolbar!
@IBAction func playPauseButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    if (!isActive) {
        play()
        swapPlayPauseButton(.Pause)
    } else {
        pause()
        swapPlayPauseButton(.Play)
    }
    isActive = !isActive
}

func swapPlayPauseButton(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem) {
    var items = [AnyObject](toolbar.items!)
    items[2] = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: barButtonSystemItem, target: self, action: "playPauseButton:")
    toolbar.setItems(items, animated: true)
}
```

Or alternatively, a solution using a property observer suggested by wltrup:

```
var timer: NSTimer? {
    didSet {
        isActive = (timer != nil)
        if timer == nil {
            swapPlayPauseButton(.Play)
        } else {
            swapPlayPauseButton(.Pause)
        }
    }
}

@IBAction func playPauseButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    if (!isActive) {
        play()
    } else {
        pause()
    }
}

func swapPlayPauseButton(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem) {
    var items = [AnyObject](toolbar.items!)
    items[2] = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: barButtonSystemItem, target: self, action: "playPauseButton:")
    toolbar.setItems(items, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Don't you also have to update the value of `isActive` in your _IBAction_? Or is its value updated in the `play()` and `pause()` methods?

Comment: It's updated in the methods but I'll add it to the solution for clarity

Comment: Ok. Personally, if possible, I'd prefer to update it in only one place, right there in the IBAction, because then the scope of that variable is very limited which makes the code at large easier to understand. Just my preference.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, that makes sense to me. I was actually wondering about where would be better to put it! I was also wondering about the order of the 3 lines in the if statement. Since play is starting a timer, would it be better to put the call to `play()` first or does that matter?

Comment: I think it's easier to read if you just use `isActive = !isActive` outside of the if block, just above the `setItems(_)` call. As for your timer question, you might want to have only the call to `play()` there and have some kind of property observer to update `isActive` and the toolbar `items` when the timer has started. I'd suggest to try the code you have now and see if you run into trouble before you make things more complicated by having a property observer.

Comment: Ok so I modified the code as you suggested and tested the app. All works well and I put the button swapping code in it's own function since it will also need to be called from the stop command if `isActive = true`. So how can I implement the property observer suggestion?

Comment: Looks good! About the property observer idea, the gist is this: `playPauseButton(_:)` gets called, then either `play()` or `pause()` gets called. They, in turn, cause the timer to start (for play) or to stop (for pause). When you start the timer, the timer will obviously not be nil, and when you stop it, you'll set it to nil.

Comment: That means you need an optional var property to store the timer and you can have an observer on it that updates the isActive boolean as well as call the `swapPlayPauseButton(_:)` method to update the toolbar. I think you'll want to use the `didSet` property observer so that the changes only happen after the timer is correctly set. You would also have to remove the updating of `isActive` from the IBAction.

Comment: I'm nearly there I reckon but I'm getting a "cannot assign a value of type nil to NSTimer" error when trying to set it to nil. How can I do that?

Comment: You need to declare the property that holds the timer as an **optional**. `var timer: NSTimer?` instead of `var timer: NSTimer`. Then, you need to unwrap it before using it. If what I just said is confusing, I'd suggest reading the section in the documentation about _optionals_, [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID309).

Comment: Ah ok! I missed that! That did the trick and it's working now. I added my code above. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Yes, but I don't think there should be a () in the declaration of the timer property. I've edited your post to remove that and also to simplify the updating of the `isActive` boolean. If I'm wrong about the (), feel free to change it back.

Comment: Yeah that's a better way to set `isActive` I tried removing the brackets but it gave an error. The fixes suggested were adding brackets or `.self` Looks like a good solution to me anyway! Thanks for the help mate I learned a lot!

Comment: Ah, the problem is that you're not declaring the property correctly. It's `var timer: NSTimer?` not `var timer = NSTimer?()`. I'll let you correct it this time around.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure I'd characterise the property observer solution as more elegant than the other. Both work equally well, I think.

Comment: Fixed and fixed :) Curious though as to what the difference is between the declarations of NSTimer? Both seem work but is one more 'correct' than the other?

Comment: The difference is that the declaration with the = and the () is the declaration of a property whose value gets set by invoking a closure, so the syntax was valid. The problem is that the closure in question had the `didSet` which, in that context, would do nothing so I think it would actually not work when you actually ran your app. Again, I suggest reading Apple's doc on setting the value of a property using a closure.

Comment: Weird I just tried it again there and it does work... Not sure what going on there but I'll do some reading as you suggest to get a better understanding. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: You're most welcome. That's what we're all here for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update the `items` property of the toolbar, either directly (but then it's not animated) or by using the `setItems:animated:` method. Take a look at the documentation for `UIToolbar` under [*Configuring Toolbar Items*](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIToolbar_Class/index.html).